# sql server remove duplicate acronym

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table look like this :

```
acronym | word
FCN     | FCN
FCN     | Fourth Corner Neurosurgical Associates
FHS     | FHS
HW      | HW
```

As you see, some acronyms have matching words and some don't. I want to keep the acronyms that have matching words. For the acronyms that don't have matching word, I'd like to keep the acronym itself. I expect the result table to look like:

```
acronym | word
FCN     | Fourth Corner Neurosurgical Associates
FHS     | FHS
HW      | HW
```

I cannot think of a way to accomplish this yet. Probably grouping by "acronym" and choosing "word", but what algorithm can decide to remove "FCN" or "Fourth Corner Neurosurgical Associates"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming there can't be any 'bad' words:

```
DELETE myTable
  FROM myTable del
 WHERE [acronym] = [word]
   AND EXISTS ( SELECT *
                  FROM myTable lw -- Longer Word
                 WHERE lw.[acronym] = del.[acronym] 
                   AND Len(lw.[word]) >  Len(lw.[acronym]) )
```

Or do you want to avoid deleting `SQL|SQL` when there is a 'bad' other (longer) record that reads eg. `SQL|Strange Things Happen` ?

Rereading the question I'm now in doubt if you really want to `DELETE` those records, or simply want to `SELECT` from it with the bespoken records filtered out. In the latter case you'd have to use (including mellamokb's advice)

```
SELECT [acronym], [word]
  FROM myTable mt
 WHERE [acronym] <> [word]
    OR NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                      FROM myTable lw
                     WHERE lw.[acronym] = mt.[acronym] 
                       AND lw.[word] <> lw.[acronym] )
```

Comment: Technically speaking, `Len(lw.[word]) > Len(lw.[acronym])` isn't what was requested, though it make common sense.  Why not just use `AND [word] <> [acronym]`?

Comment: I guess that would work too... I simply assumed that `word` would be the long version of `acronym` and didn't think further. Going for 'just different' would probably be OK too. My initial thought was to check if the `word` would fit the actual `acronym`, so `Len()` already is a major simplification =)

Comment: @deroby - Is this okay if you only want to select and not delete ? I can't modify this query to do a delete `select a1.acronym, a2.word
from 
(
select acronym, COUNT(acronym) as cnt
from acronyms
group by acronym
) as a1
left join acronyms a2 
on a1.acronym = a2.acronym
where (cnt > 1 and a1.acronym = word)
`

Comment: I want to select those records (not deleting some records). Thank you for rechecking the question

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev - As you can try here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/57781/3 your query doesn't quite return the requested records, in fact, it seems to return specifically those you want to exclude.

Comment: can there be any query optimization here? The query works but takes a long time to load the result

Comment: Depends, do you already have indexes on the table? Assuming you have an index on `acronym` (and if possible `word`) the query should run fairly fast... (how many records are in your table?)

Comment: more than 1000. I think you're right that I should index "acronym" and "word"

Comment: `CREATE INDEX idx_name ON myTable ([acronym]) INCLUDE ([word])`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your data, you may be able to use a combination of Distinct and a Case statement

```
select distinct acronym, 
(case acronym when word then word else acronym end) as Abbr 
from acronyms
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
create table #t (acronym varchar(100), word varchar(100));
go
insert #t values
('FCN', 'FCN'),
('FCN', 'Fourth Corner Neurosurgical Associates'),
('FHS', 'FHS'),
('HW', 'HW');
go

;with x as (
    select *,
    row_number() over(partition by acronym order by case when acronym=word then 1 else 0 end) as rn
    from #t
)
delete x where rn <> 1;
```